# Bootup problems

Tags: boot, refit, customizer

I have installed Refit but I could not get my mac to boot up in Ubuntu by default so i installed Grub Customizer but Grub does not load when I reboot only Refit.

The problem with Refit is that my wireless mac keyboard only works if i made a boot from os x if I boot from Ubuntu the keyboard does not work and then by default Refit boot into Mac OS x :-).

If I have used Mac OS x and then boot into Ubuntu my keyboard only workes after I have tuned it on and off under the menu in the top right corner in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

First, rEFIt has been abandoned. I've picked up development and forked it as [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) so you might want to try that instead; however, I've made no changes to rEFInd that would be likely to solve the problem you describe. That problem is basically one of drivers and hardware initialization by the firmware, which is inadequate to get your keyboard working from a cold boot. In theory, this problem could be solved within rEFInd, but I (or another programmer who wants to tackle it) would need access to both hardware and documentation. I lack the former, and I haven't gone looking for the latter. (UEFI documentation is copious, but trying to find documentation to solve a specific problem is very difficult because it's poorly organized and strangely unhelpful.)

As a workaround, I suggest you look into the `default_selection` option in `refit.conf` or `refind.conf` (depending on which program you're using). This option is much more flexible in rEFInd than in rEFIt, but in either program, you can use it to change the default boot loader that rEFIt/rEFInd launches.